# Fit the text in box using <div> and css in html

Tags: html, css

For example, I want to make the border around text with `<h1>` and `<p>` and I don't know how to do it, I tried all solutions I found on the internet but still doesn't work.

Any answer to this?

Comment: have you tried using the style tag border? its more of a css question then a php one

Comment: `Fit the in box using <div>`  -  `For example I want to make border around text with h1 and p1` Your question's title and description is conflicting... So what exactly are you trying to do? In general, I'd recommend checking the [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section first

Comment: Can you show an example of what you tried and how it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example here:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: azure;
}

h1 {
  border: dotted;
  text-align: center;
}

.dotted {
  border-style: dotted;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>A dotted border</h1>
<p class="dotted">A dotted border</p>
<div class="dotted">A dotted border</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the solution here you should use `border`.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

For example

```
p.dotted {border-style: dotted;}
p.dashed {border-style: dashed;}
p.solid {border-style: solid;}
p.double {border-style: double;}
p.groove {border-style: groove;}
p.ridge {border-style: ridge;}
p.inset {border-style: inset;}
p.outset {border-style: outset;}
p.none {border-style: none;}
p.hidden {border-style: hidden;}
p.mix {border-style: dotted dashed solid double;}
```